# Firebase-Datebase node criteria

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to how firebase node updated. 
For example, if I'm building quiz app and want to know how fast current user answered correct answer.

node would be like this

```
"correct answer": {
      "user1Id": "date",
      "user2Id": "date",
      "user3Id": "date",
      "user4Id": "date"
  }
```

Node would be updated by time order or some other criteria? 
If I want to know which place user 2 got, should I retrieve date and compare? or just iterate through and if match with user2Id then stop the iteration? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it absolute time in the universe upon which users are racing?  My first idea would be to measure the interval (on the client) between the presentation and answer of a question.  Record those to the server, and the winner is the user with minimal interval.

Comment: I mean, if node updated by time order, for example user2 answered a second later than user1, node would look like above right? But if node would look like this `"correct answer": {
      "user2Id": "date",
      "user1Id": "date",
  }`, I should compare the date right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of reasons why the key-value pairs in that object will not be sorted in order of when they were set, including that property order on javascript objects is not guaranteed.  That plus non-determinism on the network, on the app server, in the timestamps if they're generated by the clients, and you can be certain that you should be uncertain about the order.

The better representation, imo, is something like:

```
"correct answer": {
    userId: { presentedAt:"client time in UTC", answeredAt:"client time in UTC" },
    otherUserId: ...
}
```

Then determining a winner is then a matter of sorting by the interval between presentation and answer.

```
let _ = require loadash or underscore
let sortedUserIds = _.sortBy(Object.keys(answerObject), key => {
    let times = answerObject[key];
    return times.answeredAt.getTime() - times.presentedAt.getTime();
});
// the first object in sortedUserIds is the winner, second is runner-up, etc.
```

I don't know your game, but I think this approach would be most "fair" to the users.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it would be simpler to compare for response time, however, there could be a boolean which prevents other users from responding when any of them have already responded. Tip, Use the FireStore!